# Laravel Eloquent API Resources in Sequelize & Nest.js?

Tags: typescript, laravel, eloquent, sequelize.js, nestjs

Is there anything like Laravel's Eloquent API Resources in Sequalize.js & Nest.js?
API Resources allow you to transform any model to JSON by a certain pattern.

For example, if the "Post" model has attributes:

```
- id
- user_id
- text
- parent_id (id of the parent's post if the current post is reply)
```

, you can recursively retrieve the full tree of posts (replies) using this resource:

```
class PostResource
{
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'text' => $this->text,
            'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
            'parent' => new PostResource($this->parent),
        ];
    }
}
```

and with this relation in model:

```
 public function parent(): BelongsTo {
     return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'parent_id');
 }
```

And then you can use it in you contoler like this:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return new PostResource(
        $post
    );
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    id: 2,
    user_id: 1,
    text: '456',
    parent_id: 1,
    parent: {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        text: '123'
    }
}
```

I need this functionality in my Nest.js project.

The closest thing I have found is a data trasfer objects (DTO) but they are just json patterns without many functions.

So I got this in my DTO:

```
export class postDto {
    readonly id: number;
    readonly user_id: number;
    readonly text: string;
    readonly parent_id: number;
    readonly parent: object;
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
  @Get(':id')
  getPost(@Param('id') postId: number): postDto {
    const data = await this.postRepository.findOne<Post>({ where: { id}, include: ['parent'] });

    const post = postDto();
    post.id = data.id;
    post.user_id = data.user_id;
    post.text = data.text;
    post.parent_id= data.parent_id;

    const parent = postDto();
    parent.id = data.parent.id;
    parent.user_id = data.parent.user_id;
    parent.text = data.parent.text;
    parent.parent_id= data.parent.parent_id;

    post.parent = parent;

    return post;
}
```

I hate this solution to be honest.

1. there is no recurse
2. it is ugly and long

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In Nest.js, there isn't a built-in equivalent to Laravel's Resource and Collection classes. However, you can explore third-party libraries and packages to help simplify the data transformation and formatting process.

One such library you might consider is [@class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/class-transformer) The class-transformer library allows you to transform plain objects to specific classes, which can be useful for shaping your DTOs or response objects.

Example:

```
import { plainToClass } from '@nestjs/class-transformer';

class User {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const fromPlainUser = {
  unkownProp: 'hello there',
  firstName: 'Umed',
  lastName: 'Khudoiberdiev',
};

console.log(plainToClass(User, fromPlainUser));

// User {
//   unkownProp: 'hello there',
//   firstName: 'Umed',
//   lastName: 'Khudoiberdiev',
// }
```